# Error installing Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010

When trying to install [Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75568aa6-8107-475d-948a-ef22627e57a5&displaylang=en), I get the error: `The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable.`

It has to do with RiaServices.msi. Here's the log: http://www.yourfilelink.com/get.php?fid=636068

Comment: There's also a log specifically for the failed MSI installer at `file:///C:/Users/Matthew%20Sotoudeh/AppData/Local/Temp/Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%202010%20Service%20Pack%201_20110322_195004837-MSI_RiaServices.msi.txt` which might have more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method downloads the files to a temporary area on your hard disk from over the web. The chances are good that one of Microsoft's servers is having trouble sending you the resources required for the install. Try the ISO install method. This way you can rule out the network congestion as an issue.
[VS 2010](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=210710)

Win7 has ISO moint tools build in or you can use (my fav) [elby soft cloneDVD](http://www.elby.ch/fun/software/)

FYI, RIA is most likely referring to Rich Internet Applications - the 'web install' method - this can't find the resource it needs.

Comment: How do I mount an ISO drive using Win7 without 3rd party tools?

Comment: That's my fault, I was confusing ISO burning and mounting - burning is built in. I use Elby for mounting. http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html